# Issue with okhttp3 on Android

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo

We upgraded our Expo-ejected app to ExpoKit 31 and the upgrade guides says to add

```
implementation('host.exp.exponent:expoview:31.0.0@aar') {
  transitive = true
  exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
  exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp-urlconnection'
}
```

When building the app we get the following error:

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDevMinSdkDevKernelDebug FAILED
>   D8: Program type already present: okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket

Do you know how we can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove this line

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
```

from your `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 3):

They added some info. Specifically to remove:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
```

Check this: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit#upgrading-expokit